# How to remove reloading of page when user click on components in sidebar of vue-styleguidist

Tags: vue.js, documentation, query-string, vue-styleguidist

I am currently using "vue-styleguidist": "^4.36.1" version and I have some string params in URL.It is loading perfectly fine until click event happens on components in side bar of vue-styleguidist.
Once click event happens, whole page reloads ad string params in URL are getting lost.

Please check in this link:
https://vue-styleguidist.github.io/basic/index.html?name=zzz

Once page loads click on any component in side-bar and we can see that name parameter is getting removed from URL. But I need to have those to make condition based rendering

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why you don't just store them anywhere else, like in the `localStorage`, and just check if they changed or not on reload?

Comment: @StevenSiebert Thanks for the quick reply. Currently I have done in a similar way. I just thought of checking is there any configuration in styleguidist for overriding the way their routing mechanism are implemented.